# Carrera Vengeance Headset replacement/upgrade

Tags: headset

the headset on my daughter's Carrera Vengeance is showing signs of wear, so I'm looking to replace it.  I know it's a 44mm semi-integrated head set, but there seem to be numerous variants available.  Does someone know the correct details to make sure I get the correct one.  Looking at something like an FSA if possible, as I have had a few of these over the years and have been impressed by the feel and longevity.

Sorry, if this has already been asked - I did search, but could not find anything.

Roy

Photo added as requested...
[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  Could you add a picture?  That might help people trying to find a match.  You might also try searching for the original specs of the bike; that might tell you its length which is hard to judge from a photo.  (If you can't find the specs, do you know the year and size of the bike?)

Comment: @DavidW Carerra is one of the house brands from Halfords (UK chain selling car parts, bikes, some camping gear etc.).  Detailed and accurate specifications don't seem to be published, or at least not retained.

Comment: Photo added as requested - there doesn't appear to be any identifying marks that I can see on the headset.  Not sure what year the bike is - most Vengeances look the same, apart fromthe orange ones!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the 44mm known dimension and photo that shows something that looks like part of bearing cup, it is very probably ZS44/28.6.

To make sure that a replacement is compatible, you need to take exact measurements and disassemble the setup enough that you can measure the crown race at the bottom. The entire system of headset standards is explained for example [at Park Tool website](https://www.parktool.com/en-int/blog/repair-help/standardized-headset-identification-system).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  From the Park Tool website link, I would agree ZS44/28.6 looks like the correct one.  Time to strip things down and get the verniers out.